# Item list with 2 columns: 1st should wrap long text, the 2nd must not

Tags: css, responsive

I have a product list, with just 2 columns.

The 1st column: contains the Product-Title - and may contain short or long text.

The 2nd column: contains the Product-Price - formatted with the currency symbol, the numeric value, a blank-space, and then the currency code (e.g. USD)

I need a responsive design that wraps the fist column, but not the 2nd.

I have, arbitarily, set the width of the 2nd column to a fixed px, but ideally it should auto set to the longest value in the data-set.

I need a non-FlexBox solution - as we still need to support IE10,
but if someone has a FlexBox solution - that would be great for the future.

Note - I search in stackoverfow for a solution and the only full one was from 2014 which still used a TABLE approach.  Is this still true for non-flexbox?

```
<style>
.productLine {
width: 100%;
clear: both;}
.title  {
width: calc(100% - 60px); 
float: left;
overflow-wrap: normal;
}
.price {
width: 60px;
float: right;
}
</style>
<html>
<ul  class="productLine">
   <div class="title">Short example of title</div>
   <div class="price">$1.00 USD</div>
</ul>
<ul  class="productLine">
   <div class="title">Long example of title  blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</div>
   <div class="price">$20.00 USD</div>
</ul>
<ul  class="productLine">
   <div class="title">3rd example of title  </div>
   <div class="price">$1,000.00 USD</div>
</ul>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly**, change your HTML structure, you don't do divs as child element of the ul.

**Secondly**, I'd suggest you utilize the **CSS Grid system**. It has [partial support with prefix for IE10](https://caniuse.com/#search=grid) and it's the most advanced positioning system currently in CSS.

You can do something like this:

```
<div class="products">

   <div class="products__single">
      <div class="title">Short example of title</div>
      <div class="price">$1.00 USD</div>
   </div>

   <div class="products__single">
      <div class="title">Short example of title</div>
      <div class="price">$1.00 USD</div>
   </div>

   <div class="products__single">
      <div class="title">Short example of title</div>
      <div class="price">$1.00 USD</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

and the styling:

```
.products {
  display:grid; 
  grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(8rem, min-content))

}

.products__single {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 4rem min-content;
}
```

Here we've grid **two grids**, **one for the main container** that encapsulates all the products. This grid is generated by **repeat** and **auto-fit** which means it will create columns for as much width as there is available.

I've set **minmax** to set the minimum width of those columns, you can have that set to **min-content** or **max-content**.

Finally, I've made all those **individual products a grid to**o. This will address your need for column 1 and 2... where you can set a fixed value for column 1 and leave column 2 to take as much space as content needs.

One gotcha, **min-content** is inclined toward new lines where as **max-content** will mostly stay on the same line.

[here's a link to the final version](https://codepen.io/OnlyToPost/pen/BXRQdp)

Comment: 1) Thanks for correcting my HTML structure, I copied&pasted bits from the live version to try to make it simpler, without without checking ;(

Comment: 2) Your 'final version' seems to produce a 'grid card' result, rather than the tabular/2 column result I need.   Also - you say "set a fixed size for column 1".   Ideally I don't want to set a fixed width for either col.

Comment: Well, my understanding was that you're looking for containers that have fixed width on the left and floating whatever space you can take on the right..... However, it's quite easy to change it to a 2 column layout by doing something like grid-template-columns: 50% 50%... and if you don't like the fixed size, you can do a min-content or max-content on both sides.. the code would look like this => repeat(2, min-content)

Comment: @user801347 any luck with my solution ? should I update it to add more details ?